# definition of range and value for tangens

Tags: analysis

At the moment I am working on the brachistochrone solved with the Euler Lagrange equation. The candidate one gets when using it is:

$$d^2=y(x)(1+(y'(x))^2)\text.$$

To find the solution (cycloid), I substituted with tangens, which is:

$${y'(x)=\tfrac{dy}{dx}=\tan(\alpha(x))=\sqrt{\tfrac{d^2-y(\alpha(x))}{y(\alpha(x))}}} \text{ and } {x \in [0,b]}\text.$$

Now I want to find the definition of range and definition of value for this substitution. My idea would be:

FIRST

$${x \mapsto \alpha(x)} \text{ with } {x \in [0,b]} \text{ and } {\alpha \in (-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2})}\text.$$

THEN

$${\alpha \mapsto \tan(\alpha)} \text{ with } {\tan(\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}}\text.$$

Are these ranges correctly defined then? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: It’s hard to give good advice for a question like this without knowing the details of the underlying problem you’re working on. You can edit the question to provide that context.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I hope it is enough context now.

Comment: Is the added equation true? It doesn’t seem likely. There was surely some other problem you were working on when you came to this substitution. What was it? That’s what people need to know.